# ROW_NUMBER() from Derived Table with Joins is not sequential?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a derived table that contains number of joins, I am trying to implement paging but the ROW_NUMBER() is not sequential. I think I know why it isn't sequential but is there a way to force it to be sequential?

```
SELECT [Results].[Row1],
       [Results].[Row2],
       [Results].[Row3],
  FROM (
    SELECT [p].[Row1],
           [p].[Row2],
           [p].[Row3],
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [p].[Id]) As RowNumber
    FROM Table1 As [l]
    JOIN Table2 As [p] ON [l].[fId] = [p].[Id]
    JOIN Users As [u] ON [p].[fId] = [u].[Id]
    JOIN Questions As [q] ON [p].[Id] = [q].[fId]) As Results
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    with tempTable as (
    SELECT [Results].[Row1],
           [Results].[Row2],
           [Results].[Row3],
      FROM (
        SELECT [p].[Row1],
               [p].[Row2],
               [p].[Row3],
        FROM Table1 As [l]
        JOIN Table2 As [p] ON [l].[fId] = [p].[Id]
        JOIN Users As [u] ON [p].[fId] = [u].[Id]
        JOIN Questions As [q] ON [p].[Id] = [q].[fId]) As Results

    ) select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) As RowNumber, * from tempTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do an `ORDER BY Results.RowNumber` at the very end?

Comment: To be honest the order by is irrelevant to me, I just don't understand why the ROW_NUMBER() isn't sequential?

Comment: By sequential you mean ordered, or do I misunderstand the term? If so, that's because you haven't specified how the query should be ordered; depending on the query plan chosen by the query analyzer (including index use etc.) operations can be used which aren't keeping the order. `ROW_NUMBER()` counts rows, and since you do a join you might have mutliple rows with the same `[p].[id]` but with unique row numbers. Use `RANK()` or another function if you don't want this, or be more specific on the ordering in the `OVER (ORDER BY)`.

Comment: No, sorry, what I mean by sequential is that the ROW_NUMBER() is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... N vs. 1, 23, 45, 67, 1345 ... N